# When to use inverted word-order like "great an option"?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, word-order, indefinite-articles

I heard this in a movie yesterday:

> That is great an option!

Why didn't he say:

> That is a great option!

How does grammar desribe such inverted phrases? Where should I use this inverted order instead of the usual "an [adjective] [noun]"?

Comment: Did you? Are you sure you heard it correctly? It's very unusual, to say the least. Can you say what came each side of the sentence?

Comment: Several sentences before and some after, will help us parse this. Can you recall the context and could you please post here for our benefit?

Comment: I must have misheard. I won't be even able to restore the context exactly. But the situation was like a girl inviting a man and he answered: ... _great an option_ (positive). I can't be sure, but that's what I heard. It matches the explanation onomatomaniak gave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My hunch is that OP misheard.

The inverted "great an option" form is used most frequently in specific constructs, such as "**so** [adjective] a [noun]" and "**as** [adjective] a [noun]". (Both of these, for what it's worth, are comparative constructs.)

Ex: *That's not so great an option.*

Ex #2: *I'd rather not live in as large a house as this.*

Ex #3: *So great a surgeon is she that she could do this operation blindfolded.*

**Edit:** Another context in which this occurs is in constructions of emphasis, such as:
*How lovely a film that was!*

Comment: The placing of the adjective before the determiner was not unknown in earlier times. For example, Shakespeare has 86 instances of ‘good my lord’. But, yes, it is now limited to the kind of constructions you mention.

Comment: There are another few like "I kid you not" and "believe you me."

Comment: @Mark those are inversions of another type. This is about putting the adjective before the indefinite article.

Comment: Possibly also OP missed an "an" -- i.e. it was "That is great as an option".  I can visualize that for example in the context of building a menu.

Comment: You must be right about mishearing. Now having read your valueable explanations, I can try to restore the sentence. It must have been emphasising construct, maybe _How great an option!_

Comment: I've spent now much time trying to find the dialogue but failed. Maybe it was "a great, great notion" :) (in 40-year virgin). Sorry for a mistake, but anyway: now I know what I wanted to know for long.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can make sense of the phrase

> That is great an option!

is if I put in a comma

> That is great, an option!

which means "Here is an option, it's great to have it".