# Sometimes the article precedes the noun and not the adjective

Tags: nouns, adjectives, word-order, articles

I have a question that baffled me for a while now, and I'd be a happier person for an answer.
Why in sentences such as

> It's not that big *a* deal.

And

> He was as nice *a* friend as you were.

Or

> Your awesome of *a* father, told me that.

does the article position itself between the adjective and the noun instead of the usual start of the phrase:

> I have *a* big house to play in.

Much obliged.

Comment: The third example *(your awesome of A father...)* is not standard English - the nearest valid construction I think of is *"Your asshole of a father told me that"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: what variety of Standard English uses *asshole*? *Arsehole* conceivably.

Comment: @Tim: Standard working-class American English is "asshole of a father". We don't putz around when we talk dirty.

Comment: @TimLymington: As Bill says, it's the standard American form. I did Anglicise it a bit by removing the near-obligatory *"muthaf*cking"*, but I kept the spelling for "authenticity".

Comment: Possible duplicate of: ["You're too clever a man"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92079/), [When to use inverted word-order like “great an option”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49961/)

Comment: @BillFranke lol. of course I agree, equines are often dirtier than arses.

Answer (score 2):

You're conflating two different constructions. The second is required when using one noun to describe another, without converting the first to an adjective.  The Irishism *He's a jewel of a boy* is the earliest I have found, but it's not unusual: in Walter Scott's *Ivanhoe* one character calls another *"Dog of a Jew!"*

The first is specific to words like *that* or *so*, used to qualify an adjective. ?*A so big deal* would never be used by a native speaker, in any context. As far as I can see, this is purely idiomatic; Shakespeare's *So fair and foul a day I have not seen* (*Macbeth*, I, 4) could be rephrased as *I have never seen a day so good and bad*, but not as **I have never seen a so good and bad day*.

Answer (score 0):

The examples you've shown are generally verbal statements that one wouldn't write down. In your sentences, "a" is a lazy shortening of other phrases. In the first sentence, it's "of a". In the second, it's "as a". The third is already correct -- "of a" is fine (although there are other issues with that sentence ... awesome isn't a noun). You are correct that using an article there on its own would be totally incorrect English.

On a side note, if one WERE writing down this style of speech (e.g. for dialogue), you might write "He was as nice-a friend as you were." to be more explicit. The way you have it written, a native speaker would be confused.

Comment: *Not that big of a deal?* So peculiar of a phrase requires some justification. And this native speaker has never hyphenated **nice-a*, and never will.